# How does Healing Spirit interact with death saving throws?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

A character is at 0 HP with two failed death saving throws and is lying unconscious on the ground, sharing the same area with the effect of the Healing Spirit spell.

What happens at the beginning of their turn? How do the timing of these effects interact?

I couldn't find any official guidance from a few internet searches, so the GM made a ruling at the time, but is there any official answer as to what should happen?

As far as I can see, the options are:

1. The character is healed for 1d6 hit points and therefore stabilized, and doesn't need to take a death saving throw
2. The character makes a death saving throw and either succeeds or fails, which may result in their death. If they're still alive, they're healed for 1d6 and stabilize.

Healing Spirit's effect:

> Until the spell ends, whenever you or a creature [...] starts its turn there, you can cause the spirit to restore 1d6 hit points to that creature

Death saving throw rules:

> Whenever you start your turn with 0 hit points, you must make [...] a death saving throw

Comment: @Szega - Thank you very much for your help, that was exactly what I was looking for.